Hibernate Found shared references to a collection error
I'm having an issue with a List(or set I tried both) in my ecommerce website where I try to add a List of Jewelry(called CartJewelry in my code) that are in the Cart entity to the Order entity and I keep getting this error Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: com.batavia.ecommerce.model.ClientOrder.cartJewelryItems. I know it's specifically that list cause when I don't pass it to the order entity it saves without an issue.
This is my "CartJewelry" entity

@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CartJewelry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "jewelry_id")
    private Jewelry jewelry;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cartJewelry")
    private List<Cart> carts;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cartJewelryItems")
    private List<ClientOrder> orders;

    private int quantityInOrder;

    public CartJewelry(Long id, Jewelry jewelry, int quantityInOrder) {
        this.id = id;
        this.jewelry = jewelry;
        this.quantityInOrder = quantityInOrder;
    }

    public CartJewelry(Jewelry jewelry, int quantityInOrder) {
        this.jewelry = jewelry;
        this.quantityInOrder = quantityInOrder;
    }

    

}

This is my ClientOrder entity:

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ClientOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
        name = "jewelryInOrder",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cartJewelry_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    )
    private List<CartJewelry> cartJewelryItems;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private User client;
    @Column(name = "total_price")
    private int totalPrice;
    @Column(name = "date_ordered")
    private Date dateOrdered;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "billing_address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private BillingAddress billingAddress;


    
    
    public ClientOrder(List<CartJewelry> cartJewelryItems, User client, int totalPrice, Date dateOrdered, BillingAddress billingAddress) {
        this.cartJewelryItems = cartJewelryItems;
        this.client = client;
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
        this.dateOrdered = dateOrdered;
        this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
    }

    public ClientOrder(List<CartJewelry> cartJewelryItems, int totalPrice, Date dateOrdered) {
        this.cartJewelryItems = cartJewelryItems;
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
        this.dateOrdered = dateOrdered;
    }

    

}


and my cart Entity from where we get the list of "CartJewelry" to give to the Order entity:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "jewelryInCart",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cartJewelry_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    )
    private List<CartJewelry> cartJewelry;

    @Column(name = "sub_total")
    private int subTotal;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;



    public Cart(Long id, List<CartJewelry> cartJewelry, int subTotal) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cartJewelry = cartJewelry;
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
    }

    
}

the controller that does the whole process:
@PostMapping("/process-order")
    public ResponseEntity<String> processOrder(@ModelAttribute("billingAddress") BillingAddress billingAddress, @RequestParam("addressPartOne") String addOne, @RequestParam("addressPartTwo") String addTwo
    , @RequestParam("addressPartThree") String addThree, @RequestParam("addressPartFour") String addFour, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        billingAddress.setAddress(addOne + ", " + addThree + ", " + addTwo + ", " + addFour);
        Cart cart = new Cart();
        ClientOrder order = new ClientOrder();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        Date currentDate = Date.from(currentDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

        if (auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated()){
            Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
            UserDetails currentUser = (UserDetails) principal;
            String email = currentUser.getUsername();
            User userFound = userService.findByEmail(email);
            cart = cartService.getCart(userFound);
            List<CartJewelry> jewelryInCart = cart.getCartJewelry();
            try {
                billingAddressService.saveBillingAddress(billingAddress);
                System.out.println("Address saved in db!");
                order.setBillingAddress(billingAddress);
                order.setClient(userFound);
                order.setCartJewelryItems(jewelryInCart);
                order.setTotalPrice(cart.getSubTotal());
                order.setDateOrdered(currentDate);
                System.out.println(jewelryInCart);
                // System.out.println("Cart cleared!");
                orderService.makeOrder(order);
                cartService.removeFromCart(cart);
                System.out.println("Order made!");
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("Message", "Registration successful! Please log in to continue.");
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).header("Location", "/browse?success").build();         
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();     
            }
        }
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Registration failed. Please try again.");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).header("Location", "/check-out?fail").build(); 


    }

Please, any help to resolve this would be great!
I tried changing it from a Set to a List, edited my relationships to see if it would fix it.
Even tried to feed the collection to a List before passing it to the ClientOrder object, it did not work.
Tried deleting the cart's list before saving the ClientOrder one but that just gave me another error:
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection: could not initialize proxy - no Session

At the very least, you should do everything in one transaction. That's why you get the lazy exception
